# Error with list and loop involving a list

Tags: python

```
choice = int()

show_list= []

def main():
    print("1. List all TV Shows")
    print("2. Add a TV Show")
    print("3. Delete a TV Show")
    print("4. Exit")
    choice = input("Please enter a number: ")
    choice = int(choice)

    if choice == 1:
      print(show_list) 
      main()       
    
    elif choice == 2:
      add_shows = int(input("Enter number of TV shows to add: "))
    
      while True:2
         for x in range(add_shows): #error
            show = [input(("Please enter your TV Show: ").strip())]
            show.append(show_list)
        else:
            break
    main()
                         
    elif choice == 3:
      remove_shows = int(input("Enter number of TV shows to delete: "))
    
     while True:
          for x in range(add_shows): #error
              show = [input(("Please enter your TV Show: ").strip())]
              show.append(show_list)
          else:
              break
      main()
    
    elif choice == 4:
     print("Goodbye")
```

---

so this is the code i have so far. i am having an issue when i choose an option, do said option, and go back to select another, that it doesnt let you do it. im not sure what the error is in my for x in range() is but trinket(online python program) is running it as an error. also my list isnt working. i can do the add a show but it is not saving.

thank you any help in advance.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Your function `main()` seems to keep calling itself. I think you should use a loop instead.

Comment: Please ident your code properly, we don't even know what the `else:break` is related to

Comment: Why are you calling `main()` in the middle of `main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you are new to python. Your code has a lot of syntax and syntactical errors. Just take a look at the code, and try to figure out what was wrong.

```
show_list= []
choice = -1

while choice != 4:
    print("1. List all TV Shows")
    print("2. Add a TV Show")
    print("3. Delete a TV Show")
    print("4. Exit")
    choice = input("Please enter a number: ")
    choice = int(choice)

    if choice == 1:
      print(show_list)   
    
    elif choice == 2:
      add_shows = int(input("Enter number of TV shows to add: "))
    
      for x in range(add_shows):
          show = input(("Please enter your TV Show: ").strip())
          show_list.append(show)
                         
    elif choice == 3:
      remove_shows = int(input("Enter number of TV shows to delete: "))
    
      for x in range(remove_shows):
         show = input(("Please enter your TV Show: ").strip())
         show_list.remove(show)
    
    elif choice == 4:
     print("Goodbye")
```

If you have any question, feel free to ask in the comments.

PS: Don't get bothered about the downvotes. Happens.

Comment: thank you so much. I see what i was doing wrong. i am very new to python and i cant find the help i need just searching on google. i was using spyder originally and it didnt tell me what the errors were. so i had no clue. i really appreciate it!

Comment: I’m curious though. Why is choice -1

Comment: Look, we are using choice variable (in the while statement) before it's actual use (to get input). So, we need to pre-occupy it with some value when it comes to first while statement  right? So -1 is just to make sure the value in choice is not 4, so that the loop doesn't terminate beforehand. You can put any value there, except 4.

Comment: Oh ookkay. I understand now. Thank you for explaining that